# Quickly differentiate and evaluate a function of several variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I differentiate a function with respect to several variables, and evaluate it at the same time? I want to specify also the variable index that I want to differentiate, and the number of times I do it for each one.

Comment: `SeriesCoefficient[]` quickly yields a scaled version of the derivative; figuring out what the scale factor is is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x y^2]
Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y]
```

This is to get the derivative to `x`.
To get, say, the second derivative to `x` and the first derivative to `y`, and evaluate in `(0,Pi)`, you would write

```
Derivative[2, 1][f][0, Pi]
```

Comment: You could of course also use `D`, but it is a bit less compact:
`D[f[x, y], {x, 2}, y] /. {x -> 0, y -> Pi}`.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. Thanks

Comment: Ps Faysal, can you mark the answer as a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way a way that avoids the syntax a bit complicated of Derivative when a function has a lot of variables.

```
SetAttributes[MultiD, HoldFirst];
MultiD[f_[params__]] := f[params];
MultiD[f_[params__], diffVars__] :=
  Module[{diffList},
      diffList = ConstantArray[0, Length@{params}];
      MapThread[(diffList[[#1]] = #2) &, Transpose@{diffVars}];
      Derivative[##][f][params]& @@ diffList
  ];
```

Example

```
f[x_, y_] := x^4 y^2;
MultiD[f[1, 2], {2, 1}, {1, 3}]
```

A similar function can be done to get a derivative as a pure function.
I wonder if there's a way to know the number of variables of a pure or interpolated function ?

```
RemoveHead[h_[args___]] := {args};
NKeys[symbol_] := RemoveHead @@@ DownValues[symbol][[All,1]];

(*For pure or interpolated functions NumberOfVariables needs to be given as option*)
Options[PureD]={"NumberOfVariables"->Automatic};
PureD[f_,diffVars__List,OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Module[ {nVars,diffList},

        If[ (nVars = OptionValue["NumberOfVariables"])==Automatic,
            (*Gets the number of parameters of the last DownValue of f*)
            nVars = Length[NKeys[f][[-1]]];
        ];

        diffList = ConstantArray[0,nVars];
        MapThread[(diffList[[#1]] = #2)&,Transpose[{diffVars}]];

        Derivative[##][f]& @@ diffList
    ];
```

Example

```
PureD[f, {2, 1}, {1, 3}]
```